# Group and sum records in this MySQL query

Tags: mysql, select

I have two joined tables, "reports" and "visits", and a query like this:

```
SELECT reports.rep_dated,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM visits
WHERE visits.vis_report = reports.rep_id) AS vis_count
FROM reports
HAVING vis_count > 0
ORDER BY rep_dated
```

That returns the following data:

```
+------------+-----------+
| rep_dated  | vis_count |
+------------+-----------+
| 2013-11-03 | 3         |
| 2013-11-07 | 4         |
| 2013-11-28 | 2         |
| 2013-11-28 | 3         |
+------------+-----------+
```

So far so good (you see that rep_dated can be duplicated, since it's not a primary key: that's because the first "2013-11-28" refers to visits done AM, and the second refers to visits done PM)

Now I'd like to SUM the visits for the same day (aka SUM visits done AM + PM), returning this:

```
+------------+-----------+
| rep_dated  | vis_count |
+------------+-----------+
| 2013-11-03 | 3         |
| 2013-11-07 | 4         |
| 2013-11-28 | 5         |
+------------+-----------+
```

And, as you already imagine, here is where I get stuck...

`GROUP BY reports.rep_dated` doesn't work... How can I get that set?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: please provide the structure for reports and visits table, or sql fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT reports.rep_dated,
       COUNT(*) AS vis_count
FROM VISITS
JOIN reports ON visits.vis_report = reports.rep_id
GROUP BY reports.rep_dated
ORDER BY reports.rep_dated
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT reports.rep_dated, SUM(visits.vis_report) AS vis_count
FROM reports, visits
WHERE visits.vis_report = reports.rep_id
GROUP BY reports.rep_dated
HAVING vis_count > 0
ORDER BY rep_dated
```

Comment: mmmm... nope, I get respectively 15, 28 and 103 (instead of 3, 4 and 5) for the three dates mentioned, since it SUMs the foreign keys "vis_report", not the number of related "visits"

Comment: What are the other columns in reports and visits tables?

Comment: Adding sample data to your question would also help.

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql When you use Group By or ORDER by you dont need to mention table name. 
Try with

> GROUP BY rep_dated